# Derivative of a function equals the reciprocal of that function

Tags: functions, derivatives

I need to solve for a function that satisfies the following condition: $$f'(x)f(x)=1.\tag{1}$$ The solution suggests that we guess and verify. The guess is $$f(x)=Cx^k,$$ which implies that  $$f'(x)=Ckx^{k-1}.$$

Therefore, $$f'(x)f(x)=C^2kx^{k+k-1}=1,\tag{2}$$ which then implies $$k=\frac12,\quad C=\sqrt2.$$ And so $$f(x)=\sqrt{2x}.$$

My questions are the following:

1. Why is $Cx^k$ the most natural guess for a functional form that satisfies condition (1)?
2. Why is it possible to (uniquely?) pin down two parameters with just one equation (2)? (I tried several other combinations of parameters, but they don't seem to work.)

Comment: Informally, derivative "decreases power" by $1$. If decreasing power by $1$ leads to the reciprocal, the initial power must have been $1/2$. Now it's just a matter of adjusting the constant, since derivative does something slightly more complicated than decreasing power by $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see if this answers you first question.

Note that $yy'=1$ can be written as $$2yy'=2 $$

Now, what is the derivative of $y^2$, using the chain rule? (i.e. $y=y(x)$, so we're diff. with respect to $x$)

Comment: This also shows that the equation is equivalent to $y^2 = 2x + K$, so there is a "one-dimensional" family of solutions, as the asker might have expected.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Aye.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution was just found on [the french Quora](https://fr.quora.com/Est-ce-que-la-d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e-dune-fonction-peut-%C3%AAtre-sa-r%C3%A9ciproque-Y-a-t-il-un-exemple-simple/answer/Andr%C3%A9-Harnist?share=3a8117ff&srid=3iJbP) :

$f(x) = (\frac{1}{\varphi})^\frac{1}{\varphi} x^\varphi$,

where $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ , the famous "golden number"

The reciprocal is $g(y) = (\varphi)^{\frac{1}{\varphi}^2}y^\frac{1}{\varphi}$,

and the derivative $f'(x) = (\frac{1}{\varphi})^\frac{1}{\varphi}\varphi x^{\varphi-1} = (\varphi)^\frac{\varphi-1}{\varphi} x^{\varphi-1}$

using the relation $\varphi -1 = \frac{1}{\varphi}$

you get $f'(x) = (\varphi)^\frac{1}{\varphi^2} x^{\frac{1}{\varphi}} = g(x)$

edit : just found this was also found and discussed [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f/34095#34095)